# Django Cannot resolve keyword 'AuctionListing' into field. Choices are: auctionitem, auctionitem_id, currentbid, id, usernameb, usernameb_id

Tags: django, join, django-models, django-orm

This are my models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class AuctionListing(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    startingbid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    imgurl = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Bid(models.Model):
    usernameb = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="userb")
    auctionitem = models.ForeignKey(AuctionListing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="item_bided", default=1)
    currentbid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

This is my view:

```
def login_view(request):
if request.method == "POST":

    # Attempt to sign user in
    username = request.POST["username"]
    password = request.POST["password"]
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

    # Check if authentication successful
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        alfa_list = Bid.objects.filter(AuctionListing__status=True)
        return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
            "alfa_list":alfa_list
        })
        ...
```

When I run login_view I get the error "Cannot resolve keyword 'AuctionListing' into field. Choices are: auctionitem, auctionitem_id, currentbid, id, usernameb, usernameb_id"

Any ideas why? is it the Models? is it the code from the view to generate the alfa_list? I'm running out of ideas...

This is the traceback

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login

Django Version: 3.1.1
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['auctions',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LINA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\LINA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LINA\Documents\CS50\commerce\auctions\views.py", line 48, in login_view
    alfa_list = Bid.objects.filter(AuctionListing__status=True)
  File "C:\Users\LINA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LINA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LINA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LINA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\LINA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\LINA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1377, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "C:\Users\LINA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1258, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "C:\Users\LINA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1084, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "C:\Users\LINA\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1481, in names_to_path
    raise FieldError("Cannot resolve keyword '%s' into field. "

Exception Type: FieldError at /login
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'AuctionListing' into field. Choices are: auctionitem, auctionitem_id, currentbid, id, usernameb, usernameb_id
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like this.

```
alfa_list = Bid.objects.filter(auctionitem__status=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In deed that is one option as stated in the Exception Value. However, what I'm tryin to understad is the reason why this code generates an error. I have seen in other stackoverflow chats where people have managed to use similar code to this one:  alfa_list = Bid.objects.filter(AuctionListing__status=True), but it is not working in this case :( So, I'm still wondering why.

Comment: Since here you are referring the `AuctionListing` model with the field `auctionitem`.